Getting "program not found" with Command::new("echo")
This is my code:
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("echo")
    .arg("Hello world")
    .output()
    .expect("Failed to execute command");

    assert_eq!(b"Hello world\n", output.stdout.as_slice());
}

Rust returns this error:
thread 'main' panicked at src\main.rs:7:6:
Failed to execute command: Error { kind: NotFound, message: "program not found" }      
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\pj_testing.exe` (exit code: 101)

What is wrong?
It is not my first attempt trying this lib. It always returns the same error.

but, i execute others commands like cls/clear and give me the same error

so... which commands i can execute?

Have you tried the obvious yet? note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace

@TanveerBadar: How would a backtrace help?

https://superuser.com/questions/1084349/where-is-the-echo-command-file-found

On Windows echo is a builtin command of cmd.exe, not an independent command that can be run from other programs. Basically if you can find the program with Windows Explorer and run it then you can run it with std::process::Command, otherwise you probably can't.

If you are able to call echo in your shell, it is possible that it only exists as a shell built-in (meaning it is handled directly by the shell and doesn't actually run a program) so no echo program may exist. Command can only call actual programs. This can be the case with echo on Windows; see this SuperUser Q&A.
If you do have an echo program, its possible that it's not in a directory listed in your PATH environment variable and some startup script of your shell makes it available.
If you absolutely need to call a shell built-in, you can invoke the shell executable (cmd.exe, bash, etc.) which all support a way to run a shell command via argument. Like this cmd /C "echo hi" but with the Command API.
Other common shell commands may suffer similar symptoms.

Maybe these links could help: for unix and for dos.
